# How do I save multiple Pandas dataframes to different sheets in a single .xlsx, in Databricks?

Tags: python, databricks, openpyxl, shutil

The following code allows me to save a Pandas dataframe df to a .xlsx file in the Databricks filestore:

```
import shutil
final = '/dbfs/FileStore/test.xlsx'
temp_file= '/tmp/test.xlsx'
df.to_excel(temp_file, engine='openpyxl')
shutil.copyfile(temp_file, final)
```

However, I have multiple dataframes I wish to save, with each one saving to a different sheet in the .xlsx. How do I do this?

Comment: For bonus points, I also have a png created in the same notebook, using R. If I was able to save this png to separate sheet in the same workbook, this would be amazing. No idea if that would be possible though.

Comment: This is covered in the Pandas and Openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
list_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

with pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_dfs, start=1):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(idx))
    
    worksheet = writer.book.add_worksheet("PhotoSheet")
    worksheet.insert_image("B2", "images/stack_overflow.jpg")
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution working with a buffer:

```
import pandas
from io import BytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine="xlsxwriter")
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 1], 'col2': [1, 1]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'col1': [2, 2], 'col2': [2, 2]})

df1.to_excel(
    writer,
    sheet_name="sheet_one"
)
df2.to_excel(
    writer,
    sheet_name="sheet_two"
)
writer.close()
buffer.seek(0)
with open("file.xlsx", "wb") as file:
    file.write(buffer.getvalue())
```

The logic is:

- Create a buffer that will contain the excel data
- Create an excelwriter object that will recieve the data and that points to the buffer
- Write the dataframes into the excelwriter object (using the sheet_name parameter)
- Save the excelwriter
- Tell the buffer to point to the beginning (it points to latest entry when you insert stuff into it)
- Write the buffer to the file.

Comment: Why bother with the buffer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil


final = '/dbfs/FileStore/test.xlsx'
temp_file= '/tmp/test.xlsx'


with pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file, engine="openpyxl", sheet="Sheet1") as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="1")
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="2")
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="3")

shutil.copyfile(temp_file, final)
```

Still no idea how to add a PNG file to one of the tabs, but this'll do for now.